# VS Debug: Macro for the External Program path

Tags: visual-studio-2013

There used to be a way to set the path of the external program path with macros.

My teams needs the ability to set this value based on their path. When we check the project file in, it overrides local settings.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the **Start external program** option in C# project Debug settings, you can use the following C# code that sets it for the selected startup project (you can run it with Visual Commander):

```
    Project startupProject = DTE.Solution.Item(((DTE.Solution.SolutionBuild as SolutionBuild2).StartupProjects as object[])[0]);
    Properties p = startupProject.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration.Properties;
    p.Item("StartProgram").Value = @"c:\my.exe";
```